# Looping through collection and modifying class based on how many is shown

Tags: lucene, jekyll

I currently have an `events` collection like so in my `_config.yml`:

```
future:true

collections:
  events:
    output: true
    permalink: /:collection/:name
```

I am trying to only show the next 4 future posts. However, I want to change the class of it's container based on if there is 0 or 1, 2 ,3 or 4 posts that are going to show up.

```
{% assign curDate = site.time | date: '%s' %}
{% for event in site.events %}
    {% assign postStartDate = event.date | date: '%s' %}
    {% if postStartDate >= curDate %}
         <div class="SOMETHING">{{event.title}}</div> 
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

So if there is 1 post that has `postStartDate >= curDate` I want to use class `.full`, 2 posts: `.one-half`, 3 posts: `.one-third`, 4 posts: `.one-quarter`.

Does anyone now how I can count and determine this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
    {% assign curDate = site.time | date: '%s' %}
    {% assign post_count = site.events | size %}
    {% if post_count == 1 %}
    {% assign css_class = "full" %}
    {% elsif post_count == 2 %}
    {% assign css_class = "one-half" %}
    {% elsif post_count == 3 %}
    {% assign css_class = "one-third" %}
    {% else %}
    {% assign css_class = "one-quarter" %}
    {% endif %}

    {% for event in site.events %}
        {% assign postStartDate = event.date | date: '%s' %}
         {% if postStartDate > curDate %}
    <div class='{{css_class}}'>{{event.title}}</div> 
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm inferring from your intended class names (`.full`, `.one-half`, etc.) that you want to dynamically resize the elements? If that is the case you can use [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes).

To answer your specific question directly though, you could use Javascript to count the number of elements and then apply a class.

Something like:

**HTML**

```
<div id="parent">
    {% for event in site.events %}
        {% assign postStartDate = event.date | date: '%s' %}
        {% if postStartDate >= curDate %}
            <div class="SOMETHING">{{ event.title }}</div> 
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %} 
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
var numberOfPosts = document.getElementById("parent").childElementCount;

if (numberOfPosts == 1) {
    var className = "full";
)
else if (numberOfPosts == 2) {
    var className = "one-half";
)
// etc....

var children = document.getElementById("parent").children;

for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
    children[i].classList.add(className);
}
```

You can probably write that cleaner but you get the idea.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear. I wanted to implement lucene not javascript.